# Google Cloud Console - SQL - Failed to Load Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I see the below Failed to load error with a tracking number when I click on the SQL option:

Failed to load
Tracking Number: c7505762059293335

I have tried clearing the browser cache, and I have also tried using different browsers - tried Chrome, Firefox and IE; I see the same issue in all three browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This message can appear for a number of reasons. It could be an intermittent issue or something wrong with your account settings. To troubleshoot do the following steps in order:

-Try to open the page in incognito mode of your browser

-Check your permissions in IAM

-If the issue persists, open a new private case on Issue Tracker mentioning your project-id by clicking [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491274&template=1161130)

Comment: Thanks Christian. I tried accessing GCP Console in Chrome incognito mode (and still saw the same issue). I also checked the permissions in IAM. I have opened a new private case on Issue Tracker.